# I have an issue with BehaviourSubject array while im' trying to bind it to a tableview

Tags: swift

I am getting this crash while trying to bind an array of a `BehaviourSubject` to a tableview:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSRangeException`, reason: ' __boundsFail: index 7 beyond bounds `[0 .. 6]`'

```
internal var _banks: BehaviorSubject<[GetBankListResponse.Response]> = .init(value: [])
```

When i tried to get to bind like below:

```
_banks.asObserver().bind(to: bankTableView.rx.items(
            cellIdentifier: banksCellId,
            cellType: DepotMobileMoneyCell.self)
        ) { row, model, cell in
            cell.topLabel.text = model.bankName
            cell.bottomLabel.text = model.bankCodeSwift
            cell.topLabel.font = cell.topLabel.font.withSize(12.0)
//            cell.leftImageView.image = UIImage(named:model.bankName)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }.disposed(by: _disposeBag)
```

I am getting `NSRangeException`. Somebody my help me solve that please.

Comment: How many elements are inside of your BehaviourSubject array?

Comment: The size of the array before passing to Behaviour Subject is 18, even after observing the array i still have 18 elements but i dont understand why i'm have this issue.